# Excel keeps changing my text values to date in my CSV file

Tags: excel, csv, date, text, formatting

I have an exported CSV file that needs to be reimported.
It has an address column having data like -
01-03, 08-01, 01-05

Upon opening the file in excel, it reads these values like dates.

I changed the column format to text after extracting the values into text as =TEXT(column,"dd-mm") and pasting the values, which shows the correct value 01-05.

However, when I close and re-open the file they are converted back to Dates again as 16-Mar, 01-May etc.

Comment: Excel will always do that if you just open the file. You need to import it, so you can specify the column format as Text.

Comment: Open csv with other text editor like notepad++ which will not change any format. If you import that csv to database table then just import it without opening by excel.